# Left a domain and now I can't log in

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain

Left the domain because of a trust issue and now windows tries to use the domain login instead of letting me input the local admin user, what should I do?

There is no "Other user" on the corner and i can't change the user, its only asking for a password.

I have switched utilman and cmd in the meanwhile to try to join the admin through netdom join but it requires admin rights.

Comment: Call your local admins. Ask them for help - they hopefully know how to check the event log.

Comment: Contact your IT department.

Comment: I am the IT departament.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making windows enforce to input the username fixed this. [Guide](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-make-windows-10-ask-for-user-name-and-password-during-log-on/)